# Are there methods to stabilizing \$V_{BE}\$

Tags: transistors, bjt, emitter-follower

For \$V_{IN}\$ >> \$V_{BE}\$ (\$V_{IN}\$ in reference to GND), the \$V_{BE}\$ is quite stable typically only varying in 8mV for silicon NPNs and gets smaller when the emitter is conducting less electricity, just like a diode. What's advantageous with a fairly stable \$V_{BE}\$ is one can simply pre-offset the \$V_{IN}\$ and the emitter buffers almost the same signal.

But when \$V_{IN}\$ get close to \$V_{BE}\$ typical value (around 0.7V) the actual  \$V_{BE}\$ varies so much more, around 140mV.

If I were to do the same offsetting when \$V_{IN}\$ is close to typical \$V_{BE}\$, you can notice some dampening on the emitter output. I can offset \$V_{IN}\$ greatly so it's far away from typical \$V_{BE}\$ (has to be at least 3V away), but that is expensive. No I can't simply do the capacitor/resistor divider technique as \$V_{IN}\$ can be DC.

Is there a method for making \$V_{BE}\$ stable at these ranges?

Comment: Considered temperature?

Comment: schematic please, not clear what you're trying to do, or what you have connected to what.

Comment: "But when VIN get close to VBE typical value (around 0.7V) the actual VBE varies so much more, around 140mV." Without a circuit diagram I have no idea what your on about.  If Vbe variation on a BJT is such a problem then use an op amp or incorporate the BJT into the unity feedback loop of an op amp if you need the extra current.

Comment: -1 because nobody knows what "Vin" means in your circuit without a schematic.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you care so much about stabilizing vbe. Seems to be an exercise without a purpose.

With that said, a few things.

1. Use negative feedback. Biasing the top base resistor from the collector rather the rail, use high value emitter resistor, ...
2. The extreme form of 1. Is to use a CCS as the load.
3. Bias the emitter negatively. So you never have to run out of headroom.
4. Use a different topology.

...

Comment: This is the very output stage. I opted for an emitter follower as that can sense the voltage at the very load. If I were to use push pull it by collectors, I'd need a feedback mechanism and that would slow down the design.

Comment: I could use a negative emitter topology. But, then again, I could simply offset the input and that would produce the same effect and be cheaper. Also, I can't use it as an emitter follower if I used a negative emitter topology. I probably should've mentioned that I was using it as an emitter follower.

Comment: I guess. I'm saying, too subtly, that the more you restrict your solution to fewer parts, the less likely you will be able to find a solution.

Comment: It's the only way to keep it fast. Sure I'd like to design this with a lot more convenience (for my sanity's sake), but this is the only way.

Comment: Then there IS no solution. If you have to go down a particular path for its pluses, you have to live with its minuses.

Comment: I agree with dannyf......use a pulldown resistor to -3 or -6 volts, so the transistor is always on. Beware of base current interacting with resistances or impedances in the base, and causing errors or oscillation.